# Why does the ember.js starter kit include jQuery 1 and the NuGet package requires v2?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, nuget, nugetgallery

I would like to use the Ember.js NuGet package but I need to support IE 8 which means I will need to use jQuery v1. That's also what's in the starter kit. Is the NuGet package really dependent on jQuery 2? Is there any way to configure my app to use NuGet for jQuery 1 and Ember?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they just chose a version of jquery.  You can just add 1.10 or whatever is the latest and reference that instead of 2.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up grabbing the jQuery 1 NuGet package along with the version 2 dependency and conditionally referencing 1 or 2 in the view. Not pretty but it works.